# 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized' won't go away

Tags: asp.net

I've been getting this error for over a day now and can't afford to waste time when my deadline is tight.  Similar code works and I can't see the difference and why this code is giving this error.  When I try to update the changes I edit on my gridview the error occurs.

my markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="diary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sDiary"
            DataKeyNames="DiaryId" EnableViewState="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DiaryId" HeaderText="DiaryId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="DiaryId" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DiaryItem" HeaderText="DiaryItem" SortExpression="DiaryItem">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DiaryDate" HeaderText="DiaryDate" SortExpression="DiaryDate">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sDiary" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT DiaryItem, left(convert(varchar,DiaryDate,120),10) as DiaryDate, DiaryId FROM a_Diary WHERE CustomerId=@CustomerId And ProcessedDate is null ORDER BY DiaryDate"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE a_Diary SET DiaryItem=@DiaryItem, DiaryDate=@DiaryDate WHERE DiaryId=@DiaryId">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerId" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DiaryId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DiaryItem" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DiaryDate" Type="DateTime" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sDiary.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BZSSSqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    sDiary.SelectParameters["CustomerId"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["c"];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: While you debug, does `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BZSSSqlConnectionString"]` give you what you think it should? The default value of the `ConnectionString` property is `""` (empty string). If it's "not initialized" then a `<connectionStrings>` element from your web.config is either missing or the name "BZSSSqlConnectionString" is wrong.

Comment: Show us your web.config where your connection strings are defiend

Comment: Have you tried using the `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BZSSSqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString` command? Note the WEB before ConfigurationManager.

Comment: thanks for your interest guys, but I've just found out what was causing it.  The enableviewstate=false was the culprit.  one little thing like that has lost me a day!  never mind eh.  don't you just love programming?

Comment: You can and should answer your own question here, I could see this being useful to others in the future.